# Uso errado das opções útil e não útil

Tags: debate

Eu sempre utilizei o SO em inglês.
Atualmente estou usando o SO em PT, tentando ajudar o pessoal do Brasil.

Estou observando em várias questões, que a pessoa tenta ajudar quem fez a pergunta é negativado. Já vi alguns casos meus e de outros usuários, que simplesmente negativam a resposta.

Também já vi casos, com perguntas com qualidade baixa, serem negativada, e derepente serem positivadas sem motivo algum.

Será que não está havendo um uso errado desta opção. Será que não devemos tomar uma ação antes que as pessoas fiquem com medo de postar respostas, pois podem ser negativadas sem nenhum motivo aparente.

Exemplo para mim: [Dúvida com helpers do mvc](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15898/duvida-com-helpers-do-mvc/15904#15904) fui negativado e não entendi o motivo, pois postei uma resposta que funciona e já utilizei. Eu como usuário o que fiz errado?

Outro exemplo seria esta questão: [Exemplo do ASP.NET Identity usando o SQL Server](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15485/exemplo-do-asp-net-identity-usando-o-sql-server), não conheço o assunto,porém iria atrás para achar a resposta e postar para a comunidade, porém, se alguém achar ela inutil ou por festa, negativa a resposta, então vale mais a pena não postar.

Comment: Não tenho conhecimento suficiente no assunto para afirmar, mas olhando a outra resposta será que a sua não dá erro se `Model` for `null`? Pode ter sido um caso de alguém votando por ter visto um problema técnico mesmo. Mesmo assim, você tem razão de apontar uso "errado" dos downvotes. Isso ocorre sim (mais ainda no SO em inglês), mas costuma ficar por isso mesmo exceto em casos graves (como votos em série de/contra alguém).

Comment: Desde que não seja por motivos errados, o caso que falou o @bfavaretto, de resto cada um tem o direito de fazer down ou up conforme ache a pergunta/resposta boa ou má. Isso depois depende do critério de cada um.

Comment: Mas a questão que eu levanto, que critérios as pessoas estão usando? Olha um exemplo prático neste post: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15995/como-agrupar-por-mes-com-sql/16019 a resposta do Motta estava certa, ele ajudou, mas porque não algo como eu fiz, devo negativar ele? eu acho que não...Ele ajudou a pessoa da forma que sabe...

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Não entendo votos negativos, e você?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4948/n%c3%a3o-entendo-votos-negativos-e-voc%c3%aa)

Answer (score 8):

Algo que eu posso relatar que ocorre desde o início do SOPT é que quando eu posto, por engano, uma resposta que não está de acordo com a pergunta, seja por desatenção ou por não ler a pergunta inteira, ganho votos negativos. No primeiro mês do SO eu levei tantos down votes que fiquei atordoado, mas isso passa, basta aprender a pensar melhor antes de responder. É tipo um treino pessoal de atenção.

Na pergunta que você citou por primeiro, percebi pelo seu próprio comentário na outra resposta que você se equivocou quanto à solução. O seu código funciona para determinadas situações, mas não no contexto da pergunta.

Em outras situações que passei, ficou evidente que, mesmo minha resposta estando certa, outro usuário postou uma resposta melhor ou mais completa e negativou a minha por a achar talvez simples demais ou não tão boa quanto a dele. Isso pode ser feito honestamente por alguém que conhece do assunto e quer enfatizar a melhor prática ou desonestamente por alguém que quer ter a própria resposta como aceita.

No entanto, tenha em mente que a maioria das pessoas não vota considerando sua intenção ou não de ajudar, mas a qualidade do conteúdo. Pelo menos é este o meu entendimento.

Pense em quem vai acessar a pergunta depois em busca de ajuda. Se tiver uma resposta "mais ou menos" ali no meio com alguns up votes por "boa intenção", isso pode prejudicar a pessoa, que vai tentar em vão resolver o problema dela.

Sendo um pouco egoísta agora, posso dizer que quando eu acesso o SO em busca de ajuda ou referência, prefiro encontrar 1 resposta que funcione com muitos up votes e as outras que não funcionam com down votes, assim fica menos ruído para filtrar. Lógico que em várias ocasiões as respostas se completam, este foi um exemplo.

Além disso, cuidado com respostas do tipo: "Tente isso..." + um trecho de código. Tenha um pouco mais de trabalho e contextualize o erro do OP, além de porque sua solução funciona, talvez linkando uma documentação sobre a solução adotada. Isso passa mais segurança para quem lê sua resposta, não apenas como se fosse um chute, "tentativa e erro".

Pessoalmente, se eu não conheço o assunto e a reposta não está errada, não dou down vote. Mas também não dou up vote, a não ser que ela acrescente algo. Prefiro deixar a resposta lá, no cantinho dela.

Ah, e quando quero só ajudar alguém rapidamente sem gastar tempo, posto um comentário, não uma resposta.

Enfim, isso é um pouco da minha experiência. Espero que te ajude.

Comment: Já me aconteceu de ter uma resposta com -3 de início, o que fiz foi apaga-lá porque não estava a contribuir nada para ajudar a responder a pergunta, tenho de admitir.

Answer (score 4):

Eu sou novo no SOPT, algumas perguntas e algumas respostas foram negativadas para mim no começo (Com toda razão, depois de um mês de SOPT, que aprendi e refleti sobre), porém eu entendo que aqui tem toda uma cultura diferente de todas as plataformas de ajuda que já participei, por isso devemos nos adequar tanto a fazer perguntas, como também responder alguém. Por fim, respeitar o feedback do outro e sempre tentar melhorar a cada pergunta ou resposta nova.

Comment: "Cultura diferente de todos os [outros] fóruns que já participe"... pois é, começa que aqui as pessoas evitam se referir ao site/ferramenta por esse nome xD

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2068/o-stack-overflow-em-portugu%c3%aas-%c3%a9-um-f%c3%b3rum#comment6490_2068

Comment: Perdoe-me, eu quis dizer que essa plataforma é superior a tudo que já vi na internet. Mas,  obrigado pelo  toque.