# O Stack Overflow em Português é um fórum?

Tags: debate, suporte, proposta-para-faq

Sempre que alguém se refere ao site como "fórum", logo surge uma enxurrada de comentários dizendo que aqui não é fórum, que aqui funciona diferente, que isso ou aquilo não é permitido.

Por que aqui não é um fórum? Quais são as diferenças entre o Stack Overflow em Português e os fóruns de discussão que todos conhecemos?

Comment: Não vou citar fórum nem motivos, mas na minha opinião os fóruns se tornaram uma plataforma medíocre pelo péssimo uso e moderação. E ler que o SO é um fórum dói a alma.

Comment: Para mim é simples Q&A é Q&A e fórum é fórum, chamar de "fórum" um Q&A não vai matar ninguém, mas instruir educadamente a quem fez tal referencia, também não mata ninguém :) apenas a minha opnião

Comment: "... e os fóruns de **discussão** que...". A distinção tá justamente ai, na palavra "discussão". Apesar de por aqui também ocorrerem algumas eventuais *em comentários*, o conteúdo principal (perguntas e respostas) não tem a intenção de promover discussões, e sim o apontamento *objetivo* de problemas e de suas soluções.

Answer (score 85):

## Fóruns

[image: Ilustração: bagunça de fórum]

Em um fórum típico, **as respostas não precisam se dirigir a quem "abriu o tópico"**. Algumas são comentários ou contestações de outras respostas, outras são novas perguntas – geralmente "estou com o mesmo problema, alguém conseguiu resolver?"

Além disso, **a ordem das postagens costuma ser cronológica** e **as discussões tendem a se estender** por várias páginas. No caso de perguntas objetivas, isso é ruim, pois *a melhor resposta é apenas uma entre muitas, e portanto **é difícil encontrá-la*** – especialmente se você chegou no tópico via mecanismo de busca.

A estrutura dos fóruns **favorece debates de ideias e opiniões** e não perguntas objetivas – e mesmo no caso dos debates ***o nível de ruído** costuma ser alto* em relação ao volume de conteúdo útil. Felizmente têm surgido [*alternativas*](http://www.discourse.org/) que buscam resolver esse problema.

## Stack Overflow

[image: Ilustração: organização do SO]

O sistema do Stack Overflow (utilizado nos diversos sites da Stack Exchange, incluindo o SOpt) foi concebido para evitar o **["problema dos fóruns"](https://web.archive.org/web/20110909131806/http://scobleizer.com/2009/11/02/the-chat-roomforum-problem-an-apology-to-technosailor/)**, dando maior **visibilidade aos melhores conteúdos** e **reduzindo drasticamente os ruídos**.

E como ele pretende fazer isso?

- Perguntas e respostas recebem votos, e assim **a comunidade elege os melhores conteúdos**.
- O autor da pergunta pode marcar uma resposta como aceita. <strike>A resposta aceita é exibida antes das outras</strike> (edit: não é mais, mas ainda fica um V verdinho indicando), e por padrão *todas as respostas são ordenadas por quantidade de votos* (idealmente representando sua qualidade).
- Toda pergunta e resposta **pode ser editada**, o que significa que seus **conteúdos são constantemente aprimorados.** Além disso, qualquer usuário pode editar qualquer conteúdo (porém edições feitas por anônimos ou [usuários com poucos pontos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) precisam passar por aprovação de membros mais experientes da comunidade).
- As perguntas **precisam ser claras**, e as edições permitem que esclarecimentos posteriores sejam incluídos na própria pergunta, não em postagens separadas.
- **Discussões e opiniões são desencorajadas** pois tendem a gerar ruídos. Por isso não se deve responder perguntas confusas com suposições. E também por isso existem os motivos de fechamento como "ampla demais" e "baseada em opiniões". Porém *[isso não quer dizer que qualquer forma de discussão e opinião seja proibida](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/486/good-subjective-bad-subjective)*.
- Assuntos tangenciais e pedidos de esclarecimento **devem ser postados como comentários**, e quando possível esses comentários devem levar a uma edição para complementar a pergunta ou resposta. Tenha sempre em mente que **os comentários são efêmeros**, e podem ser apagados a qualquer momento pelos autores ou por moderadores.
- Toda resposta **deve se dirigir à pergunta, nunca a outra resposta**. Respostas que não atendam a esse requisito serão excluídas (ou, em determinados casos, convertidas em comentário por um moderador).

<sub>Bonecos de palito copiados do [xkcd](http://xkcd.com), graças a sua [licença](http://xkcd.com/license.html) Creative Commons.</sub>

Answer (score 15):

Acho que a diferença fundamental é de *software*. Este foi desenvolvido para restringir certos comportamentos (comuns a fóruns) e fomentar outros (comuns a wikis), e além disso limitar-se a problemas e soluções sem conversas paralelas.

AP (autor da pergunta) hipotético:

> *Mas o site e o conceito são tão legais, pena que não dá pra usar como fórum de discussão...*

Talvez tenha sido um dos motivos que levou um dos fundadores do Stack Overflow a desenvolver

[image: discourse logo]

<sup>*"[Discourse é um projeto](http://blog.discourse.org/2013/02/the-discourse-logo-a-system-of-rainbows/) que tenta reinventar **uma tecnologia que não mudou muito desde o ano 2000, web-fórums**."*</sup>

O projeto é de código aberto e o *look'n'feel* são [totalmente familiares](https://meta.discourse.org/t/forums-as-seen-on-tv/5366) para quem frequenta o SO.

Vale a pena lembrar que no SOPT:

- discussões sobre o próprio site são [conduzidas aqui Meta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). Opiniões e discussões são bem vindas, desde que seguindo o formato Pergunta e Resposta e o assunto seja o funcionamento do site principal.
- a rede [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/) oferece uma série de [salas de bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/?tab=all&sort=active) onde <sup><sub>[***Odeio XML***](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17798259#17798259)</sub></sup> é um tema de discussão válido.

Comment: Você notou que linkei pro Discourse na minha resposta, né? Na palavra "alternativas".

Comment: Sacanagem, o vídeo do post do Jeff não toca no Brasil: *
This video is not available in your country*. Vou procurar um proxy.

Comment: Deve ser questão de `a:visited color` e um pouco do excesso de bold na resposta, mas não, não tinha visto :)

Comment: É, o excesso de bold está me incomodando também. Mas são tantos pontos a enfatizar... Não rolou nem com proxy o vídeo :(

Comment: Fiz uma tentativa de alternar itálico com bold lá mas não consegui achar uma lógica para usar nos links também (que podiam ser todos itálicos)... Q acha?

Comment: Melhorou, vou tentar limpar ainda mais. Obrigado!

Comment: @all Relacionado: [*Stack Exchange clones*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2267/185667)

Comment: E [Odeio PHP](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17979916#17979916) também :P

Answer (score 7):

Achei isso na internet

> O fórum é um lugar físico ou virtual empregado para reunir-se, trocar
>   ideias e experiências sobre diversos temas.
>
> O fórum é um espaço utilizado como cenário de intercambio entre
>   pessoas que desejam discutir sobre problemas específicos ou qualquer
>   tipo de tema. Trata-se de um espaço físico em que os indivíduos se
>   reúnem presencialmente, ou então, de forma virtual, como por exemplo,
>   através da Internet.

... Artigo http://queconceito.com.br/forum

Eu chamava o **SOpt** de forum e isso me fez ter uma baita discussão com um colega aqui que durou um bom tempo. O colega não levou para o lado pessoal e eu também não, e sempre que nos topamos aqui, ficamos de boa. Ninguém se "feriu", e isso é bom. Se sempre fosse assim, que tudo ficasse apenas nas opiniões, seria muito bom. Eu deixei de chamar de forum, apenas para não ter de volta a velha e às vezes boa discussão, mas também comecei a ter um outro entendimento da coisa e estou, ainda que relutante, a não considerar o **SOpt** como um forum. Forum se discute opiniões, teses e etc e aqui não. Tipo você posta uma dúvida e recebe aquela única ou umas das possíveis resposta, não tem opinião é a resposta certa que vale. Não sei se estou me fazendo entender, tipo, digamos que eu posto a seguinte pergunta:

Como eu instancio uma classe abstrata? Só tem uma resposta que é: **Você não consegue instanciar**. Posso, sim, responder de várias formas, mas não existe aquilo de opinião diferente. **Uma classe abstrata não se instancia e pronto**. Isso difere de um forum, por isso, estou revendo meu conceito em relação ao **SOpt**. Mas ainda existe muito de forum aqui dentro, por exemplo. Você posta uma pergunta, válida, dentro das regras, aí vem um cara que "brigou" com você em vez passada e te dá um **downvote** e ele alega que é a opinião dele. Isso se caracteriza um forum, pois não há uma moderação para aceitar ou não o **downvote**, para julgar o voto e evitar a opinião própria, sem uma razão verdadeira de ser. Pra mim vai de como você vê essas coisas. Vai de você ter o **SOpt** como forum ou não.

Comment: Exatamente isso. Ultimamente eu discuto se também não deveria ser um fórum, com as devidas ferramentas. Ser, não o asterisco, mas o todo dessa ilustração: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKd9Q.png

Answer (score 6):

Bom, a meu ver, o SO não é um "fórum". 
O SO tem diversas qualidades que o tornam muito superior a qualquer fórum, está mais para uma comunidade onde todos se ajudam a dissolver as dúvidas ou às vezes até dar um "Aviso" de que algo está errado em seu código ou até mesmo em sua resposta, possível graças aos Upvotes e os Downvotes. Tirando que o SO já tem tantas perguntas respondidas que já poderia ser considerado uma Wiki.

A palavra fórum, ou melhor, os fóruns perderam sua qualidade há muito tempo, pois muitas vezes os usuários respondem de uma forma errada que algumas vezes nem condiz com o que o usuário perguntou e isso pode o deixar confuso. No SO não. Se a resposta ou até mesmo a pergunta não fazer sentido, a gente dá uma resposta certa para as pessoas não ficar com dúvidas e poder progredir com seu programa ou aplicação. Eu já fiz várias perguntas sem sentido, mas sempre tinha alguém que editava ela até alguém responder para mim :D

> **Resumo**

Não, SO não é um fórum e sim uma comunidade que visa como objetivo ajudar programadores experientes e amadores e solucionar suas dúvidas de um jeito mais rápido e fácil sem precisar ficar navegando horas na internet buscando por uma resposta válida, lembrando que essa é **Minha Opinião sobre o assunto.**

Comment: As pessoas precisam entender que ao receber critica negativa(comentário, down votes e fechamento) os usuários não estão dizendo que *não gostamos de você e tchau*. Ao receber uma uma critica negativa(objetiva) estamos sinalizando que há, e aonde há, um problema e que esse é um ambiente técnico onde estamos disponíveis para o ajudar a se corrigir e melhorar.

Answer (score -10):

O que define uma determinada classe ou categoria de qualquer objeto são suas características: [Internet Forum - EN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_forum) e [Fórum de discussão -PT](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%B3rum_de_discuss%C3%A3o), isto posto, embora exista um esforço a se distanciar de determinadas características(através de exceções) o conjunto em sua maioria delimita sua categoria.

Dizer que o SOPT, não é um fórum é criar redundância da mesma classe de sites.

Sem dúvida o termo comunidade  Q&A, pode também englobar o termo Fórum de Discussões, pois nem todas as perguntas que são feitas e serão feitas, conseguem se delimitar a objetividade. Desta forma todas as repostas mesmo embasadas em fontes altamente persuasivas, não deixam de serem apenas opiniões.

O sistema SOPT oferece ferramentas que tornam as Q&A, itens que vão além de um fórum, mas no meu entendimento o termo não deve ser excluído em sim englobado.

Além disso  uma comunidade que não se pode dar opiniões é tida como Estado Autoritário e não uma comunidade, uma comunidade que não se recicla e que não muda suas opiniões é uma comunidade estática, sendo a web um universo colaborativo e dinâmico as mudanças inevitavelmente e naturalmente acontecem.

[Users of Stack Overflow can earn reputation points and "badges"; for example, a person is awarded 10 reputation points for receiving an "up" vote on an answer given to a question, and can receive badges for their valued contributions, which represents a kind of gamification of the traditional Q&A site or **forum**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow)

[image: Está imagem esteve presente na página de Sobre]

Comment: Quando dizemos que o site "não é um fórum", não estamos querendo discutir a taxonomia das ferramentas de interação social/profissional. O que se quer é enfatizar que este site funciona um pouco (ou até muito) diferente do que provavelmente um novo usuário imagina. É uma tentativa de ser instrutivo para ajudar as pessoas a terem uma experiência melhor aqui. Sobre seu último parágrafo, onde te disseram que aqui você não pode dar opiniões? Você acabou de postar a sua, num espaço que existe exatamente para isso.

Comment: @bfavaretto A mensagem que me propus a passar é que na minha "opinião" o termo fórum se aplica ao SOPT. Quando digo uma comunidade (estado autoritário, sem opção de opiniões) eu justamente afasto essa característica do SOPT e no final do parágrafo citado por você eu reafirmo características inerentes ao SOPT e que são inevitáveis. Não se preocupe nobre companheiro, as vezes para compreendermos um iniciante é necessário paciência, tolerância e enxergar além do que os olhos e mente que o manto da experiência acabam acobertando.

Comment: Eu não estou entendendo mais nada...

Comment: @bfavaretto se me oferecer mais elementos do que não entende posso dentro dos meus limites esforçar-me a expor com mais clareza meu comentário...

Comment: No fórum a conversa rola solta e existem postagens uma em seguida da outra e o topico aberto geralmente não precisa ser uma pergunta, pode ser qualquer coisa, como tutorial, dicas, votação... Já no Q&A, é apenas uma pergunta objetiva, com respostas objetivas também, nos comentários pode haver o tal **debate**, mas no corpo da pergunta ou das respostas não e isso que diferencia. Não quer dizer que a ferramenta define isto como um Q&A somente, mas as regras também o fazem...

Comment: ... entenda assim se você perguntar algo que for "amplo" ou "falta informações" em um "fórum normal" você poderá adicionar novas postagens dentro do mesmo tópico e continuar daquele ponto, adicionando detalhes até que finalmente você chegue a um ponto que seja possível ajudar, no entanto se fizer isto aqui no "site principal" sua pergunta será fechada, entendeu o que quero dizer com "ser objetivo"? É isso, espero que entenda que é uma critica pra te ajudar e nada mais. =)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu entendi seu ponto de vista, na minha resposta deixei claro o meu, para mim a questão não é o formato do sistema, mas que o sopt engloba o termo fórum não o excluí, isso no sentido geral do termo, como discussões e debates (mesmo que nos comentários)... Sei que o objetivo é uma pergunta objetiva como: quanto é a metade de 2+2 ? e a resposta pode ser 2 ou 3, mas ainda assim existe a possibilidade de responderem 4 e alguém falar nossa que pergunta "fraca" e começar um debate, no fim será tipo um fórum, mesmo que o nome seja Q&A, pois haverá uma discussão ...

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento brother vc é um cara de palavras sabias e leves, sendo fórum, Q&A, Sala de debate, ou qualquer outro nome, o que importa é que pessoas como vc sempre tem uma única intensão é ajudar. Como eu disse minha resposta foi no intuito de enxergar por outro prisma, um prisma que engloba o termo fórum dentro de Perguntas e respostas, mesmo que nesse formato mais restrito em termos técnicos... Amanhã se o Criador do site postar olha Nós somos uma comunidade de perguntas e respostas para termos técnicos de computação e fomentamos algo mais acadêmico ....

Comment: @MagicHat Obrigado, eu entendi o seu objetivo e realmente não levei a mal e acredite os demais também não, só estão querendo lhe ajudar. Agora só uma pergunta, como engloba se o SOpt em base limita quase tudo que o fórum promove?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento isso não elimina minha opinião de que o termo fórum se aplique... é simples vai lá e avalia a resposta como negativa, é assim que o sistema funciona e mesmo que exista 1000 votos contra ainda assim eu posso estar correto. E até agora seguindo as definições de fórum que postei nos links, não há nenhum elemento que me faça acreditar que seu eu falar "aqui no fórum" eu estarei completamente errado... Uma vez em uma prova o professor perguntou?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Limitar não é excluir, e sim ajustar. Se olhar os links que compartilhei veja as características e verá que a maioria se aplicam...

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento e como eu disse as características formam a classe o tipo e tudo mais...

Comment: @MagicHat então vou fazer assim, do meu ponto de vista agora pode ser um tipo de fórum, mas evite mencionar isto, principalmente pra usuários novos, pois se não eles irão trazer atitudes e vícios prejudiciais ao site, assim manteremos o bom funcionamento =)

Comment: @MagicHat o Stackoverflow não é um fórum, o que difere ambos é a estrutura, em fórum vc abre um tópico ai um monte de gente responde não lembra do orkut? :). Fica tanto ruído que fica quase impossível de encontrar a resposta que solucionou o problema, já, aqui no SOpt vc faz uma pergunta, ai outra pessoa responde e se a resposta solucionar seu problema vc marca como resolvido fica aquela setinha verde na resposta, indicando para os usuários que ali tem a solução que ele procura, já vai direto ao ponto simples e objetivo.

Comment: @all https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow