# Sobre cópias de artigos

Tags: debate

Não quero citar nomes ou links, mas já vi várias perguntas aqui no site que, visualmente, foram copiadas de um determinado artigo.

Era comum ver respostas copiadas (e traduzidas) do Stackoverflow em inglês. Porém tenho visto artigos que foram copiados e "transformados em resposta" aqui no site.

O problema disso é que não se trata somente de uma citação, mas é uma cópia mesmo. E geralmente, quem tem feito essas copias não têm colocado as referências no final da resposta/publicação.

Eu não vejo problemas em um usuário querer ajudar alguém com uma fonte ou citação, mas só acho estranho alguém querer dar uma resposta copiada só pra ganhar upvotes.

Eu não sei se isso poderia acarretar problemas de *direitos autoriais*, mas, para ser sincero, se eu tivesse um blog ou um site e alguém copiasse meu conteúdo e publicasse aqui, sem citar a fonte, eu iria ficar bastante chateado.

Gostaria de saber que postura deve ser tomada em tais casos:

- Sinalizar para moderação?
- Pedir para o AP citar a fonte (toda vez, mesmo que ele tenha feito isso 15 vezes)?
- Editar a resposta por conta própria e colocar a fonte no final?
- Chamar atenção de quem faz isso?

E mais:

- Se isso vem se repetindo constantemente, devo sinalizar?

Cá pra nós, pode não ser o que todo mundo pensa, mas na minha opinião copiar algo e não colocar a referência, parece ser alguém querendo ganhar os créditos por aquilo que ele não teve o mínimo de trabalho pra construir.

Comment: Relacionada (?) [Responder perguntas com reprodução de texto](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1771/4808)

Comment: Isso se chama plagio, e é coisa série. Seria interessante você citar quais perguntas ou respostas estão ocorrendo este problema.

Comment: @gato Quem está vendo a pergunta, provavelmente já sabe de quem  estamos falando. Nada contra os usuários, mas eu acho desrespeitoso (já mexi com blogs e odiaria ter meu artigo copiado na cara dura)

Comment: Quem deu o -1 também poderia se manifestar. Estamos aqui para discutir. Se quiser demonstrar seu ponto de vista sobre "porque eu deveria continuar copiando posts do outros e publicando aqui", fique a vontade

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Consegue provar que quem deu a resposta consultou de fato essas fontes? Se conseguir sinalize. Se nao conseguir é apenas uma sopusicao nao fundamentada infelizmente (eu até me sinto mal por dizer isso, mas é verdade).

Comment: @BrunoCosta se você pesquisa no google, você acha o artigo com os mesmos textos (até com o smile usado no artigo)  . Teve casos que dei um toque e o usuário editou. Isso é algo que começou há pouco tempo, então gostaria de saber como proceder

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Se é esse o caso entao parece plágio mesmo, eu sinalizava e comentava.

Comment: @BrunoCosta acho que a suposição pode ser descartada quando mais de um usuário constatou a mesma situação da mesma pessoa ou na mesma resposta.

Comment: Relacionada 2 (?) [O que faremos com conteúdo de terceiros postado sem a devida citação?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/319/4808)

Comment: Outra coisa: Não quero polemizar, só quero saber como eu deveria agir. Por mim eu sinalizaria, mas tem que ver se isso é certo diante da comunidade. Então esse post no meta é a melhor solução que obtive.

Comment: Na verdade já houve alguns casos antes, mas ficou contido, agora tem gente fazendo consistentemente e tem gente copiando a ideia. O pior é que muitas vezes o texto não se encaixa bem na pergunta, até diz mais ou menos o que foi perguntado, mas você vê que a pessoa sequer se deu ao trabalho de adaptar. Mesmo os casos onde se possa copiar, mesmo onde foi citado a fonte pode ter problema responder sem contexto adequado. As perguntas relacionadas acima já deixam claro que não pode fazer isso. Não houve um conclusão definitiva sobre o caso da cópia ser plágio mesmo, não só caso de não ter citação.

Comment: Sinalizar é bom até em caso único da pessoa (dê subsídios para o moderador). Editar, comentar é sempre bom. Exatamente até que ponto vamos é que acho que cabe discussão aqui.

Comment: Relacionado também 3 (?) http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2453/usu%C3%A1rio-novo-copiando-resposta-de-outro-site-da-rede

Comment: Uma sugestão de funcionalidade: não sei se já existe algo do tipo, mas criar um sinalizador de "plagio", sendo possivel quem achar de outro local o artigo, link ou texto, citar a fonte original, sendo aprovado em uma lista de analise pela comunidade, isso talvez vá mais de encontro com aquilo que o @utluiz [postou](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2454/14262) na minha duvida relacionada. Claro que e só uma sugestão rs

Comment: E em caso de reincidências repetidas, um acompanhamento mais de perto, um puxão de orelha, ou algo do tipo

Comment: Esse tema de propriedade intelectual é muito controverso, afinal qual a diferença entre copiar determinado conteúdo (ctrl c ctrl v) e alterar trechos apenas para "dar a entender que não foi cópia" ? Principalmente, no contexto da programação onde determinadas rotinas são iguais... 
Claro que a diferença fica nítida, quando se trata de respostas de usuários avançados, como vc, o @bacco, guilhermenascimento e você-sabe-quem... Mas quem nunca deu um ctrl-c ctrl-v ?

Comment: @MagicHat concordo com o que vc disse, mas note que o problema nem é o control-C e control-V. Eu mesmo faço isso bastante, só que eu ponho link avisando de onde eu tirei, essa é a grande diferença. O problema é a pessoa fazer, e não citar a fonte, como se a resposta fosse de autoria própria. A adaptação não serve para evitar o crédito, e sim para adaptar ao que foi perguntado. Mesmo adaptada, citar a fonte é importante.

Comment: @Bacco é importante falar isso. Imagina se eu copiasse sua resposta, postasse como minha resposta (na mesma pergunta) e ganhasse todos seus pontos. Pode até ser que você não se importe com votos, mas que ia ser sacanagem ia... Acho que fazer isso, mesmo que seja em outros sites, pra ganhar o crédito, é a mesma coisa.

Comment: @Bacco na minha opinião isso é uma grande bobagem (não colocar o autor como quem diz : eu que fiz)... cedo ou tarde fica nítido... É enganar a si próprio... Mas na psicologia isso tem um nome : auto-afirmação... faz parte, o ser humano só é perfeito devido as imperfeições...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Vamos fazer um resumo.

## Queremos respostas originais

Claro que existe exceção, tem caso que é possível usar como base outra fontes, mas o que vale mesmo é a resposta que você cria. É melhor para quem perguntou, quem for ler e até para você.

Respostas originais são mais adequadas à pergunta, ajuda mais a todos e faz você evoluir um pouco mais no seu conhecimento.

Toda resposta pode fazer referências para outras fontes que ajudem complementar sua resposta. É até desejável e a fonte confirma o que está dizendo. Referenciar é colocar um *link*, só isso.

Mas se for praticamente só o *link* aí a resposta não tem muito valor. Prefira fazer um comentário.

Você pode usar qualquer fonte de informação com base para escrever seu próprio texto ou código. Mas mudar umas palavras não é admissível. Só disfarçar o plágio não é uma opção.

Não é proibido, mas responder sobre o que você não domina não tem muito valor. Deixa para quem sabe sobre o assunto responder.

O site não foi feito para fazer uma busca no Google e copiar pra cá o que achar. Isso, quem tem a dúvida já pode fazer diretamente. [Aqui não é um fórum](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/101).

## Podemos fazer citações

Na resposta podemos fazer citações.

Podemos dizer que qualquer fonte pode ser citada. É considerado uso justo se você dizer que está citando e de onde tirou isso.

Não pode haver abusos na citação.

- Não cite longos trechos. Isso pode ser considerado cópia.
- Não cite vários trechos da mesma fonte. Pode parecer um disfarce para o plágio.
- Códigos são mais suscetíveis à cópia do que textos, principalmente se forem curtos e simples.
- Deixe muito claro que aquilo é uma citação, formatando adequadamente e dizendo que aquilo é uma citação e de onde foi tirada.
- Tem que ser pontual e para fundamentar sua resposta.

Todas as citações precisam ser referenciadas, precisa dar o devido crédito. Sem o crédito, mesmo uma simples citação é considerado plágio.

Até existe alguns raros casos que não precisa, mas eles são quase inexistentes, nem considere que existe.

## Cópias podem ser permitidas

Em alguns casos é possível copiar tudo, o código integral, até mesmo o texto. Prefira não fazer. E tenha certeza que a fonte permite isso.

Na dúvida, não copie. Só se ler em algum lugar de onde tirou que diz que pode copiar é que você realmente pode. Se não tiver escrito, não copie. Só porque está na internet não quer dizer que é público. Uma das desgraças desses tempos de redes sociais e da geração que só conhece o mundo desta forma é que muitas pessoas não entendem o conceito de direito autoral. Então se você não sabia, saiba agora que se não estiver explícito que pode copiar, é porque **não pode copiar**.

Mesmo nos locais que pode copiar, praticamente 100% dos casos exigem que seja referenciado que você pegou dali. Alguns tem regras específicas.

Um exemplo são os [sites da rede StackExchange](http://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday). Outro exemplo é a [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page).

Se você copiar alguma coisa adequadamente porque não é fácil dar uma resposta melhor, ok, se abusa disto, se a maioria das suas respostas são assim, não será bem visto. Se precisar copiar, faça disto uma exceção no seu comportamento e tenha certeza que não dava para fazer melhor.

## Cuidado com as fontes

Nem sempre as fontes são confiáveis. Cuidado! Só porque está na internet não quer dizer que está certo. Se não tiver condições de validar aquela informação, não responda baseado naquilo. Se não puder sustentar o que está respondendo, não responda. As pessoas que vão ler sua resposta podem querer saber mais do que está no texto e se você só copiou sem entender nada se verá em problemas. Pior ainda quando a informação for equivocada.

Tenha em mente que é mais difícil achar fontes em português com alta qualidade. E novamente, se você não domina o assunto não sabe se o que está lendo é bom ou não. Não use com base, não cite, e não copie informações que você não tem certeza que é boa.

## Punição

Tudo isso não são só regras do site. É legislação de quase todos os países baseados em acordos internacionais. Se fizer está faltando com a ética, que por si só deveria fazer você desistir dessa ideia, está infringindo os termos de serviço do site, e descumprindo a lei, o que é bem grave. Mesmo que todo mundo aqui ache certo copiar conteúdo e que o site queira permitir isso, não pode fazê-lo. É a lei, tem que ser seguida, não podemos deixar pra lá.

**Cópias serão apagadas** e na reincidência **haverá suspensão** da conta ou até **remoção e banimento do site**.

## Viu plágios por aí?

Sinalize indicando o melhor que puder que é um plágio. Avaliaremos o que fazer caso a caso.

Comment: Copiar algo de forma integral mas citar o textos é passivel de punição também? Acabei de ver uma resposta que o texto é cópia integral de um site, mas o mesmo foi linkado.

Comment: @diegofm evitamos punição, o que tentamos é resolver a situação. Se não há autorização, não pode mesmo *linkado*. Claro que tem que analisar cada caso, nem sempre precisamos tomar uma ação, tem muito detalhe a ser observado. Sempre é bom sinalizar.

Comment: Na dúvida, acabei sinalizando, ao menos se nada tiver errado no post, pelo menos fico tranquilo de que mais pessoas além de mim analisaram e chegaram a essa conclusão.