# Uma resposta que é apenas uma cópia de uma página da Internet é válida? O que a comunidade acha disso?

Tags: debate, respostas

Hoje eu estava vendo um [comentário que fiz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/483776/100416) outro dia sobre o assunto porque a resposta do usuário era uma cópia de alguns parágrafos de um site. Houve discordância sobre a minha opinião, mas eu só vi hoje porque não me mencionaram:

[image: Print da resposta]

Ok, bola pra frente. Mas algumas horas depois responderam à uma pergunta minha fazendo a mesma coisa, [apenas copiando e colando de um site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/486841/100416), sem nem formatar (a formatação foi realizada por outro usuário):

[image: Print da resposta]

Ambas perguntas têm pontos em comum:

- Copia e cola de outro site, sem mudar nada nem acrescentar algo
- Citação da fonte
- As fontes são blogs

Nesses casos, o que a comunidade pensa?

Isso não me parece agregar a ponto de merecer um +1, mas também não me parece tão ruim a ponto de merecer um -1 simplesmente por ter copiado (ignorando se o conteúdo é bom ou não).

Quero saber o que a comunidade acha para que eu possa orientar os novos usuários corretamente (como tentei fazer na primeira resposta citada) quando ver uma situação assim.

Comment: Isso responde? https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5430/101. Não basta citar a fonte. O conteúdo tem que ter licença permissiva clara, se não tem é plágio. O primeiro exemplo eu nem negativei porque economizo onde já foi dado negativo, mas os negativos são pela qualidade baixa da resposta e até a fonte é ultrapassada e pouco pertinente. Eu evito negativar uma cópia que é permitida, mas não gosto e me sentirei à vontade para fazê-lo, a preferência sempre foi por algo próprio, não é difícil fazer mesmo usando uma fonte, se a pessoa não faz está querendo moleza,eu não gosto disto.Há casos e casos

Comment: Como eu mesmo comentei nos posts em questão, a [Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) é bem clara: "*__Não__ copie o texto completo de fontes externas; em vez disso, use as respectivas palavras e ideias para apoiar as suas próprias*". Então a meu ver o comentário do primeiro link dizendo que pode está completamente equivocado.

Comment: @Maniero responde sim, obrigado. Sabia que já tinha visto algo assim mas não estava encontrando.

Comment: @hkotsubo quando vi seu comentário citando a Central de Ajuda já senti que minha pergunta havia sido respondida :) obrigado pela referência também