# O que é o Stack Overflow?

Tags: debate, comunidade

Conteúdo obtido da [página do tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour). Sugiro ver os detalhes.

> Stack Overflow em Português é um site de perguntas e respostas para programadores profissionais e entusiastas. É construído e administrado por você como parte da rede Stack Exchange de sites de perguntas e respostas. Com a sua ajuda, trabalhamos em conjunto para desenvolver uma **biblioteca de *respostas* detalhadas** para cada pergunta sobre **programação**.

Parece só um texto solto, mas preste atenção:

> Faça **perguntas**, obtenha **respostas**, **sem distrações**

Quando tem muitos comentários em uma pergunta ou resposta, provavelmente uma das duas não é boa e começou virar fórum. Apagar antes que o sistema sinalize como algo problemático joga o problema pra baixo do tapete, a solução é entender que passou de 3 ou 4 comentários do AP (autor da pergunta) quase sempre algo está errado. Muitos comentários é ruído.

> Obtenha respostas para **perguntas práticas e detalhadas**

Isto não impede perguntas conceituais ([veja o que está no escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)), mas que tenha praticidade, que não seja pura curiosidade e diversão (curiosidades são bem vindas se tiver uma motivação).

> As tags **ajudam a encontrar perguntas** interessantes

Coloque de início que chame a sub-comunidade a responder sua pergunta e não deixe de por uma *tag* que facilitará busca no futuro. Parte da dificuldade de achar algo para duplicatas é falta de *tags* adequadas.

> Melhore as publicações **editando** ou **comentando**

Mas além dos títulos tudo ali é muito informativo e se dominar essas filosofias você se dá muito bem por aqui, mesmo sem saber regras específicas:

> Concentre sua atenção em perguntas sobre um **problema real** que você enfrentou. **Inclua detalhes** sobre **o que você tentou** e exatamente o que você está tentando fazer.

Os pontos principais que não deve perguntar:

> - Algo não diretamente relacionado a programação
> - Perguntas que são essencialmente baseadas em opinião
> - Perguntas com várias respostas possíveis ou que exigiriam uma resposta extremamente longa

E a votação consciente é muito importante:

> **Boas respostas** recebem votos positivos e sobem para os primeiros lugares.
>
> As melhores respostas são mostradas primeiro, portanto, sempre são **fáceis de achar**.

Quando se vota em coisa que não é boa, seja por não dominar o assunto, seja porque acha que voto é *like*, seja por má fé, está prejudicando a comunidade validando algo ruim.

> Este site tem o objetivo de obter **respostas**. Não é um fórum de discussão. Não tem bla bla bla.

Veja mais em [O Stack Overflow em Português é um fórum?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/101).

O SOpt **não** é:

- um fórum
- um chat
- uma rede social
- uma terceirização de serviço ou contratação
- um local de ajuda genérica, de dar uma luz, dica, ideia, norte, ou como começar

Entenda [o que é um resposta e o que não é](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Se ainda não sabe [como fazer uma boa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) siga as dicas da ajuda do site. Resumindo:

- Procure e pesquise
- Limite-se ao escopo
- Seja específico
- Torne-a relevante para outros
- Mantenha a mente aberta

[Veja mais para entender o que ainda faltou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help).

> **Capriche, siga a filosofia do site e se dê bem**

---

Se faz necessário destacar isto porque tem muitos usuários novos, alguns bem ativos, que ainda não entendem bem a filosofia do site, o que tentamos fazer aqui que é diferente de outros lugares. E destaco o fato de não ser um fórum, muito menos rede social onde você socializa, onde você diz o que gosta. Você produz e ajuda classificar conteúdo de **qualidade**.

Tem uma [FAQ da comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/699/101) com mais detalhes.

Comment: Eu postei isso porque anda acontecendo alguns problemas e tem gente que acha que eu estou inventando regra. Está tudo em material oficial do site. Pode mudar a interpretação, pra isso a comunidade vai indicando o caminho e "jurisprudência".

Comment: Há um problema de falta de esforços por partes dos usuários novos em relação aos tópicos da Central de Ajuda. Parece ser aquela velha história "Ler o manual? Nem preciso disto, eu sei fazer.", e isso se encaixa aqui. Os usuários tem que se esforçar um pouco e ir buscar como montar uma pergunta canônica. O problema é no usuário, e talvez a comunidade não esteja sabendo como mostrar a importância de seguir essas recomendações antes de perguntar, este ponto tem que ser debatido mais a fundo. Este é meu palpite ;)

Comment: O problema é que muitas pessoas(exemplo eu) aparecem no site para tentar ajudar, e também conseguir respostas, mas são sempre "excomungadas" pelos outros usuários, que requerem que a pessoa faça uma pergunta a nível do ENEM para realmente "ser" uma pergunta de qualidade. Eu tenho perguntas que realmente não sei explicar direito, então porque os usuários não tentam entender a pergunta da pessoa comentando para ela o que ela pode fazer para ajudar? Eu mal fiz uma pergunta sobre php(que ao meu ver ficou muito clara por sinal) e já levei um report por "estar fora do escopo",