# O que exatamente eu posso publicar no Stack?

Tags: debate, stackoverflow

Eu sempre vi posts do Stack sobre diversos assuntos, e nunca entendi exatamente o que eu posso e o que eu não posso perguntar. A que assuntos o site se limita?

Comment: [Aqui ilustra](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/264/27190) os principais assuntos que estão dentro do escopo do site. No entanto, sugiro fortemente que você leia no [help](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) se quiser saber mais a respeito do que perguntar, são os principais tópicos.

Comment: em inglês, [a rede é bem grande](https://stackexchange.com/sites) - em português, temos por enquanto [o de programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) e o de [língua portuguesa](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Blogueira Obrigado

Comment: Já respondida em [O que é o Stack Overflow?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7256/o-que-%c3%a9-o-stack-overflow)