# Quais os procedimentos que um (novo) usuário deve utilizar para tentar reabrir uma pergunta que considera válida?

Tags: debate, suporte, duvida

Sou um novo usuário. Fiz uma pergunta baseada em pesquisa prévia sobre pacotes do R ([neste link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/480188/qual-melhor-pacote-do-r-para-plotar-dados-em-mapas-do-brasil)).

Minha pergunta foi fechada por ser considerada opinativa. Reli a pergunta. Vi que realmente tinha cometido um erro ao pedir por opiniões. Na verdade eu queria informações baseadas em fatos e nos conhecimentos de usuários mais experientes do que eu.

Pesquisei, então, por outras perguntas bem aceitas pela comunidade que também pediam informações embasadas em fatos, como, por exemplo, essa [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2539/as-mensagens-de-erro-devem-se-desculpar). Editei então minha pergunta para ficar mais parecida com uma pergunta bem aceita, de um usuário mais experiente. Citei a pergunta na qual me inspirei para fazer a edição.

Está correto esse procedimento? Quais os procedimentos que um (novo) usuário deve adotar para tentar reabrir uma pergunta que considera válida?

Comment: (não é resposta, só tou adiantando o assunto) Antes de tudo é bom entender o que é o site. Perguntar aqui foi um bom ponto de partida. Ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e depois o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70) pode ajudar muito. Definir as necessidades do seu projeto na questão específica pode ajudar (delimitar os pontos que levaram a fazer a pergunta, o que fez escolher as que escolheu para comparação, etc). E, finalmente, considerar que nem toda dúvida vai caber no site.

Comment: Olá doctor.phd, o motivo do fechamento é porque é opinativa, um bom lugar para tentar buscar por opiniões pode ser o chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha, precisa apenas de 20 de score (o que é bem fácil de conseguir) para participar.

Comment: Olá Bacco e Guilherme, obrigado pelos comentários. Eu li os documentos que o Bacco indicou. E eu havia entendido que fecharam a pergunta porque ela era opinativa. Tentei mudar isso na edição. Como mencionei na pergunta, não queria opiniões, mas sim informações baseadas em fatos, como a outra pergunta que citei

Comment: "Fatos" ainda sim são opiniões de pessoas que usaram, e é esse tipo de resposta que a pergunta vai gerar, eu gosto mais de X porque X tem tais vantagens, outro vai dizer, eu gosto mais de Y porque Y tem tais vantagens... Opiniões não deixam de ser verdades, só porque são opiniões, muitas opiniões são sim verdades concretas, baseadas em experiencia ou entendimento. A pergunta "As mensagens de erro devem se desculpar?", não é bem questão de opinião de sim UX (user-experience) e na pergunta esta escrito: "Respostas com opiniões sem base são inválidas e devem ser votadas negativamente." pelo autor

Comment: Particularmente eu achei a pergunta bem feita: útil, clara **e** mostra esforço de pesquisa. Entendo que dependendo do ponto de vista pode parecer opinativa (*qual lib devo usar?*), mas do meu ponto de vista é uma pergunta válida. Por exemplo, essa pergunta parece muito mais opinativa com base na maneira como foi escrita: [MySQLi vs PDO - qual o mais recomendado para usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8302/100416), mas eu também acho uma pergunta válida (e foi bem recebida pela comunidade)

Comment: Você não pode visualizar lá, mas lhe adianto teve no minimo 5 respostas deletadas nessa pergunta, "As mensagens de erro devem se desculpar?", porque foram justamente "opiniões", UX é um ramo muito complexo, nem chega a ser escopo do site, só aceitamos eventualmente como experiencia e tomando uma série de cuidados. Agora sobre qual lib, pacote, API usar, vai ser sempre baseado em "um gosto", todas podem ter vantagens e desvantagens.

Comment: Olá @RafaelTavares, permita-me discordar, mysqli vs PDO é sobre APIs nativas, ou seja, sobre o que a linguagem possui, comparar elas ali não é sobre o que é melhor, é sobre o que elas se diferem, e claro que dá para afirmar qual é melhor em algum sentido, e até saiu alguma coisa assim nas respostas, mas ali é sobre coisas nativas.... Pedir para comparar pacotes de terceiros de desenvolvedores diferentes é algo totalmente diferente disso.

Comment: Eu entendi que o autor da pergunta sobre as mensagens de erro deixou claro que não queria opiniões, mas sim informações baseadas em fatos. Procurei uma resposta muito bem aceita, justamente porque não queria apontar o dedo para ninguém que teria feito errado como eu tinha feito de início, pedindo opiniões. Queria aprender com uma boa prática. Quando achei que encontrei uma boa prática, busquei adotá-la na edição da minha pergunta, para me adequar aos padrões da comunidade. Enfim, por isso fiz a pergunta sobre quais procedimentos adotar para tentar reabrir uma pergunta...

Comment: Quanto às vantagens e desvantagens dos pacotes não acredito que sejam baseadas apenas em gosto, os pacotes tem geralmente tem funcionalidades e capacidades diferentes. Enfim, acredito que poderia ser uma pergunta útil para outros usuários caso programadores experientes em plotagem de mapas tivessem a chance de responder. Certamente seria útil para mim. Mas enfim, talvez esse seja um bom ponto de debate: quando fatos são opiniões e quando não são. Depende do tema?

Comment: Não depende do tema, são coisas diferentes, precisa compreender isso, seria o mesmo que perguntar, *"qual é melhor, Lumen ou Laravel, quais vantagens e desvantagens desses dois frameworks?"*, além de gerar respostas longas demais ainda cai muito no gosto pessoal, por exemplo, eu gosto muito de coisas bem mais simples, raramente necessito de funções prontas de LIBs gigantes, então pra mim, projetos menores e simplórios funcionam melhor, mas para a maioria não, acaba quase sempre sendo gosto pessoal, somado a vantagens e desvantagens.

Comment: Relacionado: [Good subjective, bad subjective](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/486/112052)

Comment: Um adendo. Fóruns e grupos de discussão visam fomentar o debate. O [nosso formato](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2069/137387) é diferente, o Q&A é o oposto, visa eliminar o debate e as múltiplas interações entre os usuários. Veja o [problema dos chat/forum](https://scobleizer.blog/2009/11/02/the-chat-roomforum-problem-an-apology-to-technosailor/). Perguntas que gerem discussão e conteúdo justificadamente divergente entre suas as resposta devem ser recusadas. Faltam dois votos para que sua pergunta seja reaberta.

Comment: No [*CRAN*](https://cran.r-project.org/index.html) e encontrei [isso](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brazilmaps/index.html): *Package ‘brazilmaps’ was removed from the CRAN repository.
Formerly available versions can be obtained from the archive.
Archived on 2020-05-06 as check problems were not corrected despite reminders.
The most recent check results can be obtained from the check results archive.*

Comment: Fazendo a [consulta por pacotes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/index.html) procurando por *geobr* encontrei um [resumo do pacote](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/geobr/index.html), descompactando as [versões arquivadas](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/geobr/) no arquivo *Description*:...

Comment: *Description: Easy access to shapefiles of the Brazilian Institute of Geography and Statistics (IBGE)
      <https://www.ibge.gov.br/> and other official spatial data sets of Brazil as 'sf' objects
             in R. The package includes a wide range of geographic datasets available at various 
             geographic scales and for various years.*

Comment: Oi Augusto. Sim é verdade, o brazilmaps foi removido do CRAN, precisei baixar do github. Segui um tutorial para fazer mapas com ele e está funcionando relativamente bem ainda. Mas realmente tem algumas limitações. Por isso gostaria de saber dos outros pacotes, de usuários experientes para saber em qual valeria a pena investir no aprendizado. Acho que essa é uma questão que seria interessante, pois há muita demanda para plotar dados geo-referenciados no segmento de pesquisas e de produção de relatórios. Obrigado pelos seus comentários

Comment: Obrigado a todos pelas sugestões dos ótimos documentos. O post "good subjective, bad subjective" é muito legal. E como ali mesmo reconhece, a própria distinção entre objetivo e subjetivo é até certo ponto subjetiva, e há muitas coisas úteis entre os extremos do subjetivo e do objetivo, relacionadas a experiência dos usuários que são boas p/ o aprendizado. Acho que isso é o importante: perguntas que possam gerar aprendizado. Eu procurei melhorar a minha nesse sentido graças ao feedback de vcs. E não queria travar uma discussão, apenas ouvir os usuários mais experientes. Valeu