# Conflito entre perguntas semelhantes no fórum

Tags: debate

Fiz uma pergunta aqui no site:

- [Pegar último arquivo que entrou na pasta "Downloads"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/523416/)

e um colega respondeu de forma muito elegante com um código enxuto. Na sequencia recebi a notificação de que uma pergunta similar já tinha sido feita e respondida. A notificação me orienta a editar minha pergunta ou excluí-la.

Só que, analisando as respostas da pergunta antiga vi que elas não eram tão boas quanto a que o colega deu para minha pergunta. Se eu excluir minha pergunta as respostas sumirão junto? Existe uma forma de eu compartilhar essa bela resposta aqui no fórum para que ela não se perca?

Comment: Conforme [meu outro comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/523416/pegar-%c3%baltimo-arquivo-que-entrou-na-pasta-downloads#comment951333_523421) o `glob.glob()` é péssimo para lugares aonde existem muitos arquivos, consome muita memória, para você a resposta pode parecer um código enxuto, mas não é, é um código com problemas, por isso lhe indiquei um código melhor e expliquei toda motivação em minha resposta, apontando os problemas e indicando uso melhor, no caso o `iglob` ou até mesmo o `Path().glob()`, pois ambas usam "iterator" ao invés de `list()` (caso do glob.glob()).

Comment: Este tipo de postagem não deve ser removida, ela está indexando para quem vier buscar por solução. A notificação faz sentido antes do fechamento, mas uma vez fechada, o link do quadro azul resolve o problema apontando. Por ironia, já tem um post aqui no meta sobre isso, então aqui também fiz um link ;D

Comment: Lembrando que [O Stack Overflow em Português **NÃO É** um fórum](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/137387), somo um [site de perguntas e respostas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/137387).

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, concordo com você. Eu até tinha visto sua respostas, mas na ocasião, por está apressado, sua respostas ser muito longa e tratar de várias possibilidades, eu acabei não analisando com cuidadosamente. Além do mais, eu estou pegando o arquivo em um diretório controlado com baixo fluxo de arquivos. Novamente reitero que é importante ver a aplicação do iglob como forma  de não sobrecarregar a memória nos casos em que o fluxo dados ou arquivos sejam altos.

Comment: @CarlosLourenço na verdade só se trata de uma possibilidade a minha resposta, que é usar o max() + iglob(), o resto são as explicações técnicas necessárias para explicar porque daquela forma era "melhor" ou "mais pratica" (métodos nativos pronto para tal uso). Que bom que você compreendeu, estou atualizando a resposta para ter o código do iglob fácil de copiar.