# Não deveríamos ter alguma opção para solicitar a revisão perguntas de perguntas fechadas?

Tags: debate, perguntas-fechadas

Há 4 anos tive uma pergunta fechada "por estar fora do escopo", porém sei que a pergunta permaneceu relevante e ativa desde então, em especial aos Desenvolvedores Brasileiros através de comentários e up-votes, e na minha opinião está dentro do escopo, porém não é um escopo muito comum à todos os desenvolvedores pois está num nível de complexidade bem acima da média.

Porém,

> Nem sempre é claro quando algo está dentro ou fora do escopo, portanto pode ser necessário, coma a ajuda da comunidade, reformular a pergunta para que ela fique adequada.

Então talvez o movimento da comunidade não deveria ser editar e melhorá-la ao invés de fechar? Afinal quem vota para fechar geralmente tambem tem permissão para propor edições.

O processo de reabertura é feito através da edição apenas, num fluxo oculto à primeira vista, tornando complexa a experiência do usuário:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Uma terceira opção poderia ser desenhada para que usuários mais novos solicitassem à usuários experientes edição de acordo com o escopo e regras da comunidade.

A pergunta que cito no inicio é esta: [Como configurar a ordem correta de certificados para solicitar certificados e-CPF e e-CNPJ do ICP-Brasil?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/195053/7130)

Ela foi:

- Perguntada 5 anos atrás.
- Modificada 4 anos, 8 meses atrás (2 meses depois porque foi o tempo que levei para solucionar o problema).
- Vistada + de 3 mil vezes.
- Favoritada por 4 pessoas.
- Recebeu 10 votos positivos (fora os negativos né, vai saber).
- Vinculada a 4 perguntas pois é basal para entendimento do conceito de obtenção de certificado.
- Amplamente comentada, inclusive dezenas de pessoas me contactaram fora do site por causa dessa pergunta.

Não existe uma opção de solicitar revisão do fechamento ou algo do tipo, apenas a opção de editar ou remover:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu não sei se hoje, 5 anos depois, a resposta ainda é relevante ou talvez não tivesse outra resposta mais atualizada, mas como está fechada para novas respostas não poderia ser atualizada.

Comment: Como assim termos uma opção para solicitar a revisão perguntas de perguntas fechadas? Todas as perguntas fechadas quando editadas automaticamente entram numa fila de revisão e reabertura de perguntas. Todas as perguntas quando recebem um voto de fechamento ou sinalização de usuários automaticamente são encaminhadas para uma fila de revisão de qualidade. Quanto a sua pergunta é de boa qualidade(vou deixar meu voto), mas acho que está um pouco fora do nosso escopo somos especificamente devs e a pergunta é voltada para devops.

Comment: Pra vc não aparece a opção de "Reabrir"? Deveria estar junto com os links de "Compartilhar", "Editar", etc. Ao clicar nesta opção, a pergunta é enviada para a fila de reabertura. Se não tiver essa opção, o outro procedimento é justamente o que vc fez, que é trazer a discussão aqui para o Meta - ou seja, já existe "*opção para solicitar a revisão de perguntas fechadas*" :-)

Comment: A 5 anos atrás esse conceito de devops nem era tão difundido assim, hj temos essa separação mais marcada, mas antigamente todo o fluxo da aplicação era feita pelo programador.
Porém devops não é fora do escopo, temos ate tags https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags como aws, azure, devops, azure-devops, etc.

Comment: Realmente, existe a opção na edição e vou editar a pergunta original.

Comment: LeonanCarvalho, a imagem da opção que o @hkotsubo citou [aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUhSS.png), veja a documentação [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions).

Comment: @AugustoVasques Talvez a opção não apareça para o Leonan porque ele é o autor da pergunta? Não lembro de todas as regras...

Comment: @hkotsubo, aparece sim. Eu tenho pergunta fechada e excluída e para mim aprecem as opções de reabrir e restaurar. [Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/450924/como-realmente-prevenir-a-inje%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-c%c3%b3digo-ao-usar-a-propriedade-element-inner) deixei um voto para reabrir e um voto para restaurar minha própria pergunta.

Comment: A 5 anos atrás eu já ouvia em todos os cantos pessoal falando de devops, o problema de devops aqui não é por falta de ser difundida, a questão é que devops envolve mais equipe, decisões e regras. Já existe site na rede especifico para isso, o [devops.se]. As tags existirem em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags não significa que o assunto está [no escopo](/help/on-topic), só significa que pessoas criaram perguntas e junto com elas criaram tags, as perguntas continuam sendo fora do escopo, inclusive um dos trabalhos como moderador é eventualmente remover tags que não deveriam existir.

Answer (score 5):

### Já temos processo de revisão.

E a revisão com reabertura pode ocorrer por diversos meios:

- A edição é um dos meios mais comuns.
- O voto de reabertura é outro.
- A reabertura voluntária (não "provocada") pela comunidade é mais um.
- Ainda, tem o caso de trazer para o meta (isso se nada mais der certo, para evitar ruído desnecessário).

O que ocorre é que a postagem já foi para a fila de revisão, mas como é fora do [escopo do site](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70), na revisão a reabertura foi rejeitada.

**Mas a discussão deu algum fruto**. Havia sido fechada por vários usuários com a mensagem de "melhore a pergunta" (o que sugere edição para arrumar). Este fechamento não é o mais adequado, então aproveitando a discussão, corrigi o motivo de fechamento. (o que deixa mais claro que não é caso de melhorar para reabrir, e sim de não ser um assunto pertinente).

Note que a quantidade necessária de votos para reabrir hoje é tão baixa que é quase impossível um fechamento equivocado durar muito tempo (no caso, mesmo com 46 visitas nessa discussão no meta no momento dessa resposta, não obteve os 3 votos de reabertura).

O Stack Overflow (especialmente o Stack Overflow em Português) é bem claro no aspecto do foco no desenvolvimento de software. Já tivemos várias discussões no meta sobre vários temas colaterais (como devops, suporte, infraestrutura, docker, questões de licenciamento), e o problema cai sempre no mesmo: preservar a qualidade do conteúdo em vista do público alvo (não só pelas contribuições, mas pela melhor qualidade dos votos, de forma que as postagens sejam classificadas por pessoas da mesma área).

O [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70) também pode ajudar no entendimento da finalidade do site (mas tem várias outras discussões interessantes no meta).

Ainda, como já mencionado nos comentários, perguntas fora do nosso escopo podem caber em outros sites da rede como no [Devops](https://devops.stackexchange.com), [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com) ou em alguns casos até no [Super User](https://superuser.com). A rede já é segmentada em [assuntos bem definidos](https://stackexchange.com/sites) desde sua concepção, e isso não é obra do acaso.

Vale notar que já [tentamos um Super User em português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=super+user), mas a proposta foi rejeitada pela empresa. Quem quiser tentar outro tema para site em português deve visitar o [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) e fazer a proposta (mas em vista do que ocorreu com o Super User, creio que não vai acontecer)

Comment: Bacco, sei que está a tempo aqui, mas não podemos esquecer: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1/aqui-n%C3%83o-%C3%89-o-stackoverflow-com

E justamente por não termos um Devops em PT ou Server Fault em PT é que torna a pergunta relevante. E principalmente por ser algo especifico aos programadores brasileiros, aonde se concentra o maior número de falantes da lingua portuguesa.

Comment: Por isso, eu discordo, e acredito que a pergunta está totalmente dentro do escopo.

Comment: Esse argumento de não termos um [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/) PT ou [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) PT tornar a pergunta relevante não faz sentido, se nos pautarmos nesses sofismas começaremos a receber e aceitar perguntas sobre roteiros de viagem só porque não termos um [Travel SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/) PT ou perguntas sobre dicas alimentação saudável porque não termos [Veganism & Vegetarianism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/) PT.

Comment: @LeonanCarvalho discordar é seu direito, mas a decisão é da comunidade em geral. A imensa maioria escolheu diferente do seu entendimento, o que resta é acompanhar. Teve todo um processo no Area 51, o negócio tem bem mais seriedade do que parece. Depois disso, como já explicado, já tivemos muitas discussões sobre abrir o escopo no meta, e a comunidade deixou claro que não quer isso. Até tentamos uma vez, faz alguns anos e o resultado foi péssimo. Esse é um assunto meio que esgotado. Na hora que uma maioria significativa de usuários mudar esse entendimento, os votos refletirão isso naturalmente.

Comment: A pergunta é sobre certificados digitais para configurar um servidor web, está no mesmo nível de uma pergunta sobre como configurar reescrita no apache
 https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102722/o-que-significam-rewritecond-e-rewriterule-em-um-arquivo-htaccess/102731#102731
Que também deveria ser fechada e postada no server fault. Entendem? 2 pesos e 2 medidas aqui.

Comment: @LeonanCarvalho fechei. Longe de ser a primeira com resposta minha que fecho. Como já disse, tentamos abrir o escopo e o resultado não foi bom (veja a data da pergunta do seu link). Outra coisa que não é boa é criar caso nos comentários (insistência gasta tempo seu e meu à toa). Utilize seu privilégio de voto onde achar necessário conforme a pontuação permite, é assim que a comunidade decide. Não são só moderadores que tem privilégio de abrir ou fechar perguntas, as postagens seguem seu caminho natural conforme a comunidade julgar (não tem espaço nem pra "pesos e medidas" diferentes aqui).