# Perguntas sem codigo no StackOverflow

Tags: debate

Se alguém fizer uma pergunta sem código apenas pedindo ideias de como resolver um determinado problema de programação é considerado pergunta inválida e tenho de sinalizar?

Vejo algumas perguntas no StackOverflow sendo fechadas por não pertencerem ao escopo, porém não deveria de ser permitidas essas perguntas?

Programação não é só código, é preciso projetar primeiro.

Comment: Ter ou não código não pode ser usado como critério isolado para se avaliar uma pergunta – ou votar nela, sinalizar, etc. Precisa sempre ver a pergunta como um todo. Se está dentro do escopo (o que também não é tão simples de definir), se dá informações suficientes para ser respondida, se pode ser respondida decentemente num espaço restrito, entre outras coisas. Sempre tem que olhar a pergunta como um todo, independente de ter ou não código.

Comment: Todas as perguntas que vejo sobre alguem com duvidas acerca de um exercicio sem codigo para a faculdade ou para auto aprendizagem é sempre fechada. É provavel que haja pessoas com esperança que façamos o codigo por elas, mas em vez de darmos o codigo poderiamos dar sugestões e como pegar num certo exercicio.

Comment: O problema é ter que dar sugestões totalmente no escuro. A maioria dessas perguntas é só um enunciado, não dá nenhuma dica sobre o que a pessoa do outro lado sabe ou não sabe. É difícil ajudar sem saber de onde partir.

Comment: Se nem o autor, na maioria das vezes que vejo, teve esforço algum em tentar algo, por quê nós é quem deveríamos? Eu aprendi programação por querer aprender, por pesquisar, perguntar pessoas que sabiam mais que eu, professores, tentar me por a prova, não foi colando enunciado em um site e ficar sentado esperando respostas cairem do céu não. Se a pessoa não sabe nada, provavelmente ela não se dedicou o suficiente, porque com um minimo de dedicação, por  mais dificuldades que tenha, ela vai ter noção de algo ali, e isso já facilita ela explicar a duvida um pouco.

Comment: Sim claro, óbvio que concordo, mas por vezes há enunciados que para uma pessoa sem experiência são complicados e se calhar bastava uma dica que já era o suficiente para conseguir resolver. Eu sei que a maioria queria era um código todo resolvido, a minha sugestão é tentar guiar essas pessoas de maneira a dar dicas e não a dar um código pronto.

Comment: A proposta do site é ter perguntas e respostas objetivas (conforme resposta do Maniero abaixo), então a ideia de *somente* dar dicas não se encaixa exatamente neste modelo. Apesar que muitos acabam dando algumas dicas em comentários, o que já é alguma coisa (não é bem o que vc está propondo, mas de certa forma isso já meio que acontece). De qualquer forma, perguntas do tipo "dêem-me dicas/ideias" geralmente são amplas demais e/ou baseadas em opiniões - e ambos são [motivos de fechamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: Provavelmente estava a confundir um pouco com um fórum e estava defendendo o meu ponto de vista, porque um dia posso precisar de ideias ou algoritmos mais eficazes para um trabalho que posso vir a fazer, sem necessariamente já ter feito, apenas em fase de projeto.

Comment: Eu não sou das pessoas que faz isso, ape as gostava de perceber como funciona o stack overflow, parece que todos estão a negativa-me e a deitar-me abaixo... É suposto ouvir opiniões

Comment: Inclusive é possível o cara praticamente fazer um curso aqui no site fazendo uma pergunta por vez, até aproveitando o que já foi respondido. Não é ideal, mas dá para fazer, em geral não fazem porque dá trabalho e a pessoa não quer ter trabalho. No momento que a pergunta é "faz pra mim", ferrou :) Veja https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxo3W.jpg. Se a pessoa souber usar o site pra fazer isto vai se dar muito bem. Ele pode fazer quase tudo aqui mesmo.

Comment: Nós estamos a falar de coisas diferentes, concordo a 100% com isso, eu próprio quando comecei a aprender programação não sabia do stack overflow, ficava horas e horas descobrindo meu erro é foi assim que aprendi e ainda continuo aprendendo por aqui.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Se não tem código e a pessoa não quer código pode até ser respondido se tiver informações suficientes para responder em linhas gerais, o que pela nossa experiência não costuma acontecer, em geral a pessoa não tem informação suficiente e muitas respostas podem ser certas ou erradas e só o autor consegue saber se está certo ou não. E também temos experiência que nem o autor da pergunta, vulgo AP costuma saber o que resolve para ele, e escolhe uma quase aleatoriamente, não ajudando outras pessoas e dificultando ou impedindo de outras pessoas poderem avaliar, porque não se sabe qual é o problema mesmo.

Tem um tipo que pergunta que não tem código, só o problema, e geralmente é bem definido (nem sempre, por mais incrível que pareça), e isto é o enunciado de exercício que a pessoa precisa resolver e não tem ideia. De forma geral isto é fora de escopo. E é comum a pergunta receber negativos porque há uma falta de esforço. Perguntas assim podem ser feitas, se a pessoa souber colocar a dificuldade, demonstre algum esforço e fique claro que ela precisa de uma **resposta** objetivo a uma pergunta objetiva. Coisas do tipo "preciso que faça tudo pra mim", "preciso de uma ajuda geral", "não sei por onde começar", ou parecido com isto não costuma ser aceito. E há quem negative até quem responde por colaborar com algo que não ajuda de fato quem perguntou.

Claro que tudo tem que ver o contexto, sempre há casos e casos. Mas quase sempre quem sabe perguntar bem não faz este tipo de pergunta. Em quase um paradoxo que o problema dessas perguntas é que a pessoa tem dificuldades anteriores à programação.

O problema de deixar aberta é que aprecem respostas voluntariosas que ou entregam tudo pronto que não é objetivo aqui, e que pode dar votos fáceis, porque isso as pessoas não gostam, ou vira [um fórum, o que não somos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/101), e a pergunta vira quase um debate, fica tendo muita interação, praticamente um curso interativo, que não é o objetivo do site. Raros os casos que sai alguma coisa que que **seja útil para muitas pessoas**, que é objetivo do site. Em geral depende da pergunta ser boa e quem responde saber fazer de forma apropriada. A maioria das tentativas geram postagens vagas que até podem ajudar, não não respondem o que foi perguntado de forma adequada e útil para todos.

O [foco do site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) é em ajudar com problemas específicos, ou conceituais, ou sobre ferramentas de programação, ou algoritmos, ou problema **práticos**, não teóricos.

Se a pessoa quer algo sobre o projeto do software ele precisa perguntar sobre isto, por exemplo não faz sentido ela colocar [c](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) se ela só quer aprender o algoritmo. Ela coloca porque ela quer o código pronto. Mesmo que só queria o algoritmo , também é fazer pela pessoa.

Se ela disser onde está a dificuldade pode ser que seja interessante. Em geral ela diz que o problema é que ela não entende nada, que a dúvida é em tudo. Fica difícil ajudar essas pessoas.

Pelo menos hoje é assim. Eu já sugeri que poderia mudar, mas a ferramenta tem que mudar junto.

Comment: Eu já percebi, eu estava a pensar de maneira diferente da que o site funciona.