# Pode-se fazer perguntas relacionadas sem ser de código?

Tags: debate, suporte

Fiquei com uma dúvida ao vir perguntar aqui no fórum, mas como não achei nada muito específico sobre, achei melhor perguntar aqui se alguém já passou por isso.

Por exemplo, eu queria perguntar se da para reutilizar modem de tv a cabo (hdtv) ou modem de internet (aquele mais novo que vem incluso até antena) ou até mesmo um roteador antigo para fazer qualquer coisa bacana que seja (Mesmo que seja utilizando algum raspberry), mas fiquei na dúvida se uma pergunta dessa se encaixaria com o tema do fórum.

Afinal, esse tipo de tópico é aceito ou não faz parte da ideologia do fórum ter perguntas desse tipo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primeiro, aqui [não é um fórum](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/101). Isto é mostrado no [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour), uma página que ninguém lê e depois reclama que ela fez tudo certo e mesmo assim foram maldosos com ela.

Sua pergunta claramente não é sobre programação, é sobre hardware. Na [Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help) tem essas informações, especificamente na seção sobre os [tópicos que aceitamos aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Pode-se fazer perguntas que não possuem código, mas tem que ter uma relação direta com programação (indireta muita coisa pode ter, mas como aqui é um local de programadores fica difícil responder sobre coisas que apenas tangenciam programação).

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento :)