# O stackoverflow é um grupo de discussão?

Tags: debate

Pois é, apesar de já está a um certo tempo por aqui, descobri que não e isso depois de me envolver em uma treta com o moderador @maniero.

Sim, descobri que o stackover não é o que eu preciso e o tipo de comunidade que eu quero participar. Eu sou das antigas, sou um mero programador autônomo de sistemas, sou da época do yahoo grupos, grupos do orkut, google grupos e até grupos de discussão da revista info exame :).

Não quero reputação, não busco reconhecimento, não quero ser um criador de conteúdo para o stack, quero apenas ajuda para problemas, muitas vezes fruto de exigências de clientes e ajudar outros com seus problemas quando eu souber e só.

Depois do desentendimento e de até ser injusto com o colega @maniero fui pesquisar qual era realmente o objetivo dessa tão na moda rede stackoverflow e foi quando percebi que não é o que eu preciso e o que eu busco.
Busco apenas ajuda e ajudar sem me preocupar com padrões, protocolos ou se vou ter qualquer reconhecimento por isso. Ajudar outros para mim é apenas uma forma de retribuir a ajuda que eu recebo e não espero nada em troca por isso.

Por fim quero aqui deixar minhas desculpas ao caro colega @maniero e agradecer pelas várias ajudas com as encrencas que recebi aqui. Mas realmente vou me dedicar a participar de outro tipo de grupo, talvez os específicos das tecnologias que eu utilizo. Assim consigo ser mais livre, fazer as 10 linhas só de contextualização que eu gosto de fazer não me importar se o título não está adequado ou se tem tags fora de contexto, etc, etc, etc. Afinal não sou um criador de conteúdo sou apenas alguém com uma dúvida e também tentando sanar a de alguém.

Comment: Não querendo parecer mal educado, mas custa assim tão pensar um bocadinho no título e nas tags? Não sei se percebeu mas a ideia de ter melhores títulos e as tags adequadas ajuda as pessoas a responder à sua dúvida.

Comment: Não exista problema com as perguntas antes do stack existir, todo mundo escrevia da forma que quisesse e ainda assim as perguntas eram respondias o conhecimento era compartilhado e a vida seguia. Ai chega o stack e então se descobre que as pessoas “não sabem perguntar” pode haver um objetivo nisso agora entendo o propósito da rede. Mas sim, para mim custa, tempo é dinheiro.

Comment: Não existia?! Sempre que alguém quisesse saber de uma coisa qualquer teria de ir lá perguntar ou então procurar nos longos tópicos antigos a resposta certa. Hoje em dia eu sempre que tenho uma dúvida pesquiso e venho ter ao stackoverflow. Porque alguém já perguntou a mesma coisa, porque tem títulos sugestivos e, normalmente, posso encontrar a resposta certa logo a seguir a pergunta. Eu praticamente resolvo todos os meus problemas a pesquisar no stackoverflow. Raramente tenho de fazer uma pergunta, porque ela já foi feita por alguém.

Comment: Isso sim é partilhar conhecimento. Mas pronto, são gostos. Cada um com a sua ideia.

Comment: Não via a treta, não estou por dentro do assunto, mas vou só dar uma dica para te abrir a mente com outras coisas. Muito do sucesso do StackOverflow, é porque as pessoas **encontram o que procuram**, ou seja o conteúdo da pergunta, é super importante para os motores de busca indexarem corretamente as coisas. Então o cuidado com o título, as tags corretas, usar uma imagem, etc, ajudam muito no SEO do conteúdo, e serve para outras pessoas com problema semelhante pesquisarem no Google e encontrarem a resposta no Stackoverflow. Apenas uma dica como falei. []´s

Comment: E nesse formato sempre é buscado respostas mais canônicas possíveis, o que além de ajudar o autor da pergunta ajuda outras milhares que acabam chegando no tópico. Em fóruns afins dificilmente se busca isso e tende a criar dezenas de tópicos paralelos discutindo a mesma coisa, não sendo difícil encontrar inclusive tópicos conflitantes sobre o mesmo tema. O formato do SOpt está longe de ser o ideal e costuma ser bem difícil de acostumar para quem vem de fóruns, mas se mostrou muito mais efetivo.

Comment: Relacionada ou duplicata: [O Stack Overflow em Português é um fórum?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/5878)

Comment: @Jorge B, isso para mim nunca foi problema, problema é algo subjetivo. Em fim, existe quem esteja disposto a participar na criação de todo esse conteúdo altamente padronizado e organizado, não é o meu caso. Mas é louvável todo aquele que se dispõem. Como eu disse eu sou das antigas e é a forma que mais me agrada e onde eu me sinto mais a vontade. No mais é isso, bom trabalho aos colegas.

Comment: Não vou falar especificamente de ninguém, vou fazer uma análise geral do que eu vejo os usuários que usam o SOpt. O SO se tornou um sucesso estrondoso justamente pelo que falaram. Aqui tem qualidade, e você consegue achar tudo o que precisa facilmente. é diferente de fóruns tradicionais que só servem para ajudar a pessoa e é egoísta e um desperdício de recursos enorme, as mesmas coisas tem que serem respondidas toda vez, e pior, muitas vezes de um jeito ruim, que é o pior que pode acontecer, afinal se for completamente errado a pessoa percebe. O ruim a pessoa acredita que teve ajuda e se ferra

Comment: É muito comum acontecer isso com as pessoas é o tal do https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect, a pessoa não liga, ela só quer ver funcionando https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgk8Q.png, não importa que seja ruim, que atrapalha de alguma forma, ela não quer evoluir se tornar profissional, não importa quantos anos mexe com isso ela não é experiente. E assim não dá valor para o que fazemos aqui e não entendem o quanto é importante ajudar outras pessoas para se ajudar, a pessoa nunca vai reconhecer isso, é um problema de atitude.

Comment: O Sopt é um divisor de águas na vida profissional de muita gente, apesar de todos os problemas que ele tem hoje, e quase todos relacionados ao fato das pessoas esterem querendo usar como se fosse um fórum, ou pior ainda, um helpdesk. E algumas pessoas sempre terão a atitude de "o que importa sou eu, não importa comunidade, não importa ajudar os outros, não importa eu me esforçar para que os outros tenham menos trabalho para me ajudar, não importa se vão me responder algo bom e estritamente correto, só quero ver funcionando".

Comment: Independente disso o SO(pt) mesmo não tanto quanto no passo continuará sendo um local para se produzir conteúdo de qualidade para ajudar milhões de pessoas porque ele não só é bem respondido e classificado com bom por bons profissionais que possuem reputação, em pontos ou além disto, mas também porque as perguntas são boas para serem respondidas. Fechei como duplicata, mas no fundo parece fora de escopo, é só um desabafo.

Comment: Ficou extenso o assunto, mas eu tiro de bom daqui que você entendeu que o perfil do site não corresponde ao que se dispõe a fazer, e vai fazer a ação mais inteligente, que é procurar um lugar mais adequado ao seu perfil. Isso é melhor para você e para o site (e continuará bem-vindo aqui). O que eu acho incrível é quando é diferente (acontece bastante) de usuários recém chegados (e alguns mais insistentes) acharem que o site todo tem que mudar para atender às expectativas específicas deles. Infelizmente, em muitos casos, isso até é reflexo até da educação (ou falta dela) das novas gerações.

Comment: Ok, entendo seu desabafo, mas sempre participei e ajudei muita gente muito antes de o stack existir, sempre funcionou para mim e foi dessa forma que cheguei até aqui. Para mim não se trata de egoísmo se trata realmente de eu não me agradar do formado da rede. Por isso decidi realmente me envolver em outras comunidades mais identificadas com o meu perfil. Sim era uma bagunça antes, mas responder a mesma pergunta varias vezes nunca foi um incomodo para mim. Aqui não faço muitas respostas aqui exatamente por causa das restrições da plataforma.

Comment: Não sou egotista, apenas não me agrado com o formato da rede. Prefiro uma comunicação mais fluida e dinâmica. Se observar bem o meu texto eu citei varias vezes ajudar e ser ajudado.

Comment: Quanto a “querer apenas ver o código funcionando” isso renderia um novo grande debate. Mas pra resumir tem gente “rica” desenvolvendo soluções em delphi 7 programando de forma esturrada mesmo já sendo farto as informações mostrando as vantagens do OOP.

Comment: Isto não é desabafo, estou explicando o Stack Overflow. O desabafo é seu. O formato não te agrada não participe, não interessa para a comunidade se você prefere participar de outras comunidades, você está fazendo exatamente o que eu disse, "eu, eu, eu". Lamentamos que seja assim, mas não precisa postar algo no meta para dizer isso. A não ser que queira que o formato mude para atender suas demandas. Isto não vai acontecer. Você quer ajudar do seu jeito, aqui tem um jeito e você não quer se adaptar a isso, infelizmente não dá *match*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because é apenas um desabafo e não algo que interesse à comunidade e que permita alguma melhoria.

Comment: Já que se sente obsoleto,atualize-se, hoje em dia não precisa criar uma publicação para externar que está deixando um site, comunidade ou grupo social, apena deixe. E pior Isso aqui não é uma rede social onde estamos interessados em debater os seus ou nossos sentimentos. Isso aqui é publicação técnica ambientada segundo um formato técnico(que é líder no segmento) objetivando solucionar problemas de maneira técnica voltada para o publico técnico. Então se tem uma critica quanto ao formato a faça de forma técnica.

Comment: Quanto a tretas. Uma coisa que percebi é reação emocional que algumas pessoas tem com relação a orientação. Leve em conta que comentários não possui volume e nem voz, é somente texto contendo uma informação a ser decodificada. Volume e voz são construtos gerados por nossa mente para facilitar a digestão do conteúdo e a percepção de força e intensidade desses volume e voz tem mais haver com seu próprio estado emocional do que a mensagem propriamente dita.

Comment: @AugustoVasques perfeito!

Comment: @AugustoVasques esse é o detalhe. Embora um texto não possui voz, dependendo de como ele é escrito, pode fazer o leitor se sentir muito mal. Falo por experiência própria, pois alguns e-mails que já recebi e mandei deram a entender que era algo muito diferente do que estava-se escrevendo

Comment: @riki481, diferentemente de uma rede social, nosso conjunto de instruções é reduzido a poucos tópicos como a formatação das perguntas e respostas, clareza das perguntas e respostas, pertinência das perguntas e respostas, amplitude das perguntas e respostas, escopo das perguntas e respostas,... é uma coisa quase mecânica. Tem gente que aceita e tem gente que não aceita ser orientado. Seja por desenvolver um vinculo emocional com a própria  pergunta/resposta ou auto presunção de perfeição. Essas pessoas tendem a se portarem de maneira passional onde bastaria um simples "obrigado pela observação"

Comment: @riki481 não vai resolver 100% seu problema com emails mas ajuda bastante http://www.labcom-ifp.ubi.pt/ficheiros/20110824-serra_paulo_manual_teoria_comunicacao.pdf.

Comment: @AugustoVasques obrigado, mas não é mais necessário. Já aprendi com esses erros de e-mail, só utilizei eles como exemplo, já que a situação é parecida.