# Não entendo votos negativos, e você?

Tags: debate

Um tempo atrás, quando criei uma conta aqui no SOpt, não sabia como perguntar (tanto que minhas perguntas só tinham votos negativos), e assim fiquei me questionando:

***Por que votos negativos?***

Depois de um bom tempo percebi que recebia votos negativos pela minha ortografia e por não perguntar com clareza.

Até aí tudo bem, fiz outra pergunta. Revisei a ortografia e os erros de português e tudo OK. Hora de publicar a pergunta!

BOOM! Publiquei, em menos de 2 minutos, 2 votos negativos.

***What?***

Fiquei me questionando novamente.

***O que eu fiz de errado?***

Li o [debate do usuário Guilherme Nascimento](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4162/usu%C3%A1rio-tentando-retaliar-com-votos-negativos-suspeita) e pensei:

***Por que todo mundo não é assim? Deu voto negativo? Explica porque e já era!***

Acho que o que passa na cabeça de um novato é isso, porque tomou o voto negativo e o que ele fez de errado pra tomar. Acredito que a rede inteira da SO devia adicionar isso, quando qualquer voto negativo ou positivo fosse dado, o sistema perguntava o motivo, o que adianta você dar um voto negativo e a pessoa não aprender com o seu erro? Eu sei que conforme mais votos negativos a pergunta tiver, o usuário é temporariamente bloqueado de fazer pergunta, e quanto ele tenta aparece uma página mostrando que ele tomou muitos votos negativos em alguma pergunta, e recomenda ele ler a página *Como fazer uma pergunta*.

As vezes me pergunto:

***Será que essa comunidade é feita de humanos ou habitantes de outro planeta?***

Será que não passa na cabeça de uma pessoa que se ela dar voto negativo, e simplismente ***que se fod#*** o usuário não vai consertar seu erro? Será que pensam que ***se eu der um voto negativo e o usuário ser bloqueado de fazer perguntas vai aprender***?

Comment: Tens alguns pontos bem pertinêntes. Um negativo com um comentário (contrutivo) é sempre melhor que um negativo a seco. Se quiseres juntar exemplos de perguntas que receberam negativos podemos ajudar a identificar possiveis motivos que podem ter levado a votos negativos.

Comment: Outra pergunta sobre negativos? Estou começando a concordar com o @brasofilo sobre esta questão.

Comment: Se serve de exemplo, estou no site uns 7 meses e nenhuma das minhas primeiras perguntas receberam negativo... Será que o pessoal foi com minha cara e me poupou disso? Ou será porque me precavi antes de entrar no site, e procurei saber como eu deveria me portar aqui com meus conteudos? Eu há pouco tempo era insistente com negativos, mas eles não causam tanto impacto quando o conteudo é bom. Esquece negativo, preocupe-se apenas que, ao perguntar, se colocar no lugar de quem le, e ver se você mesmo entende a pergunta.

Comment: Quando alguém da um voto negativo o sistema já avisa para deixar um comentário apontando possíveis falha, entretanto não é obrigatório que se faça um comentário, mas, se eu estivesse no seu lugar, me focava mais em elaborar perguntas mais claras e objetivas e com exemplos. E não adianta ficar chateado com os negativos, enquanto a pergunta não estiver clara ela vai receber votos negativos, em alguns pontos até acho prejudicial -7 negativos numa pergunta, porem, se precisar de ajuda para melhorar alguma pergunta, deixe um comentário nela pedindo onde deve se melhorada e revisada a pergunta.

Comment: @DenerCarvalho o meu não avisa quando dou negativos :D

Comment: @WallaceMaxters na primeiras vezes que negativa aparece, no entanto usuário com 2000 ou mais já são considerados experientes e a mensagem não aparece mais pra eles.

Comment: Votar negativo pela ortografia não tem pé nem cabeça... Visitar a [help] e navegar pelo site para ver como são estruturadas perguntas bem recebidas vai eliminar 90% das chances de levar -1. Auto-ajuda é algo que existe de fato.

Comment: O que não entendo são os votos positivos... esta pergunta que usa termos ofensivos e que demonstra falta de conhecimento sobre o que é uma "boa pergunta" tem 5+ e 4-.... me explica?

Comment: @DiegoF as vezes também acontece de um usuário dar o downvote por problema de interpretação. Eu mesma passei por isso ontem, tenho muita dificuldade para elaborar as perguntas pelo baixo conhecimento comparado aos dos demais. Mesmo assim dois usuários reconheceram que haviam entendido errado a pergunta (mas por culpa minha mesmo), retiraram o downvote e responderam a pergunta. Estou ainda tentando aprender e principalmente me esforçar para melhorar essa situação. Acho positivo o downvote, ele também ensina e sou totalmente contra ao downvote por vingança, não é legal. Obrigada :)

Comment: pra mim o uso de downvote é bem especifico, usuários com uma pontuação média-alta que fazem perguntas pouco claras ou respostas não relacionadas com o solução da pergunta. Caso o usuário tenha pontuação de iniciante acredito que o melhor é sempre insentivar o esclarecimento da pergunta/resposta para que ele se sinta contvidado a participar e melhorar a comunidade e não o contrário. Porém cada usuário tem autonômia e consciência para participar da maneira que melhor lhe agradar.

Comment: @pmargreff temos que ver menos o usuário e mais o conteúdo. O downvote é uma ferramenta pra apontar problemas e não para oprimir, se mal usada, tipo downvote por picuinha ele perderá o seu valor, se o downvote é para apontar uma pergunta com problema então esse downvote tem valor de utilidade sim. A questão não é ser convidativo ou não, é saber entender a comunidade e ler o Tour e Help e principalmente os links: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (como criar um exemplo para pergunta) e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice (seja respeitoso e não leve para o lado pessoal).

Comment: @DiegoF esse comentário merecia uma resposta.

Comment: @JorgeB. concordo, mesmo com várias respostas uma "experiencia" deve ajudar a tornar algumas mentes mais abertas =)

Answer (score 19):

Olha, eu já sofri alguns os quais realmente foram por desgosto de alguém com algo que comentei, ou porque simplesmente pensavam que eu estava tentando ser oportunista por acabar conseguindo responder minhas próprias dúvidas, ou por às vezes criar propositalmente uma pergunta da qual eu já tinha a resposta. Na verdade, o sistema permite isto, mas é como o @Gabe disse: não é por que é permitido que deve abusar disso (apesar que eu só fiz duas perguntas em 2014, os quais ambas tomei downvote), as que tomei downvote na época de 2015 foram após um usuário que não entendeu uma pergunta minha e começou querer encrencar e outro usuário foi após justificar o porque dei um downvote na pergunta dele.

Não posso afirmar que foram eles, mas começou o chamado *serial downvote* nesta época, todavia eu notei um comportamento padrão de alguns outros usuários que eu tenho um *certa amizade* e que jamais pensei que dariam downvotes sem justificar pra mim. Não posso afirmar com precisão, mas de certa forma foi possível notar a provável origem. Algumas perguntas minhas, eu entendi claramente os problemas, em outras eu não encontrei problema algum.

Simplesmente deixei de guardar rancor, mas me mantive "vigilante".

Sobre a sua pergunta:

- Por que todo mundo não é assim? Deu voto negativo? Explica porque e já era!

Justamente pelo motivo que citei, eu sempre justificava o downvote, mas isso me causou dores de cabeça, o problema é que as pessoas chegam aqui no site achando que downvote é sempre arbitrário, sendo que a maioria é totalmente justificável, as pessoas apenas evitam justificar pra evitar sofrerem "retaliação" (desta vez escrevi certo):

> **retaliação**
>   <sup>substantivo feminino</sup>
>
> - aplicação da pena de talião; revide com dano igual ao sofrido.
> - p.ext. revide a uma ofensa ou a uma agressão sofrida; represália, vingança.

Não tem como afirmar os motivos reais dos downvotes, mas vou tentar analisar as suas perguntas uma por uma pra lhe apontar os problemas:

- [Matriz 5x5 com Portugol - Aprendendo a programar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115117/3635)

  Possíveis problemas:

  1. Geralmente perguntas com motivos para serem fechadas também recebem downvote. Não porque a pergunta é de todo mal, mas para reforçar que ela deve ser fechada.
  2. Não foi apresentado código algum, ou o que o pessoal chama de "esforço mínimo".
  3. Apesar de não ser proibido, perguntas sobre exercícios ou tarefas de estudo não são muito bem vistas. As pessoas veem isto como "faça pra mim", e por isso colocar um esforço mínimo, tal como um código que você tenha tentado, é tão importante.
- [Verificar se há palavras em maiúsculas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/114270/3635)

  Possíveis problemas:

  - Falta de código aonde será aplicado a verificação. Quero dizer nesse tipo de pergunta, podem ser dados vários tipos de respostas, mas como não está claro aonde será aplicado o código, então se as respostas não lhe satisfazem você começa a perguntar nos comentários e dar códigos aos poucos e as respostas levam tempo até serem úteis pra você. Não foi bem o seu caso, mas poderia ser, sempre coloque o mínimo de código e que ele seja claro ou possa ser reproduzido, como descrito em [**Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
- [Usando o Google Maps API para determinada Longitude e Latitude](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/112802/3635)

  1. Os comentários lá dizem bem o possível problema, não estou dizendo que quem comentou foi quem negativou, muitas vezes quem comenta não negativa, comentários:

     > Mesmo não funcionando, é importante mostrar o código que já construiu para que possamos ajudar
     >
     > Já leu a documentação do Google Maps API (developers.google.com/maps) lá explica tudo e com exemplos
     >
     > Edite sua pergunta com o código, como você mesmo falou que já tentou.

     Talvez a pessoa tenha negativado antes da sua edição e não notaram que você "melhorou" a pergunta depois, veja que aqui mesmo no META tem um proposta pra sabermos quando houver edições em coisas que negativamos:

     - [Notificação de votos negativos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4863/3635) (Talvez isso venha a ajudar a sumir com alguns downvotes após edições)

Ao que me parece todos downvotes que recebeu **não foram injustos**, foi mais por falta de prática em você se expressar.

Não vou negar que existe mal uso deles, porque existe sim, principalmente por usuários que chegam a pouco na comunidade mas já tem uma considerável pontuação, porém pouco participam do META e geralmente inventam o próprio *"certo e errado"*, estes mesmos acham que estamos bancando os *"sádicos"* quando *negativamos* ou *fechamos* ou *damos uma crítica negativa* a postagens de outras pessoas. E por não entenderem bem a comunidade e algumas regras, eles pegam uma certa bronca então começam a **inventar** e **inverter** as coisas e até bancar os **"justiceiros"** usando votos negativos pra atacar quem eles discordam.

**Downvote não é do mal**, se bem usado ele ajuda a mostrar lugares com problemas, se mal usado ele começa a confundir as pessoas e mais serve pra depreciar, não tem como ser *"100% bem usado"*, mas se usar pra atacar as pessoas, realmente só vai virar uma bola de neve.

Comment: Eu uso downvote como último recurso, na verdade dei apenas 2 negativos até hoje. Uma resposta que receba downvote por motivo pessoal pode perder credibilidade. Usuários de fora podem perceber esse 'equívoco' e passar a ignorar o votos como avaliação e seu uso perde o sentido.

Comment: É isso ae @PapaCharlie! Concordo plenamente, é isso que eu quero dizer com voto mal usado, você expressou muito bem (melhor do que eu) o que eu quero dizer, esse é o grande problema que vivo reclamando, o voto mal usado uma hora irá acabar por perder o seu valor, eu só dou downvote se a resposta estiver com um grave problema e depois de ter comentado pro autor e ele não editar, mas pra maioria das respostas com problemas não tão graves eu geralmente forneço uma outra resposta e não negativo as demais.

Comment: Só dou downvote se a pergunta/resposta for bastante ruim ou o usuario, mesmo após fazer uma pergunta/resposta ruim e ser alertado, continuar criando outras com a mesma "qualidade", ai também haja paciencia. Normalmente, uma edição ou um comentario já resolve o problema.

Comment: Alias, ultimamente, em casos onde o OP não consegue explicar o problema, tenho usado um "grupo de perguntas" que sempre me faço quando estou criando uma pergunta ou resposta aqui, como comentario, a fim de orientá-lo. Parece bobo mas tem me ajudado bastante com o velho problema, ja até relatado aqui no meta, de "ter um problema, mas não saber como explicá-lo". Agora votar olhando usuario é algo que precisa mudar na cultura do site, mesmo que demore.

Comment: @DiegoF é realmente, tem coisas que precisam mudar na cultura do site, andei reclamando bastante sobre isso, fui ignorado e até um pouco reprimido por certas pessoas, mas vejo agora que ainda tem pessoas que pensam semelhante a mim.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Ah eu mesma fiquei super chateada no dia de hoje: pensei muito para elaborar uma pergunta e ela obteve diversos downvote e está pendente pois não foi bem aceita pela comunidade. Fiz já as edições, conforme recomendado nos comentários, espero que a pergunta volte a ficar ativa. Mesmo assim, me sinto culpada as vezes pela falta de conhecimento. Mas não por isso vou sair prejudicando os demais usuários com downvote desnecessários, isso não se faz e não é legal. E também quer queiram ou não, o downvote também é uma forma de aprender. Obrigada! :)

Comment: @IngridFarabulini acho que a situação é um pouco diferente, olhei a sua pergunta e os votos não me parecem arbitrários, é apenas um tipo de pergunta que não é bem aceita, nos últimos dias vocês tem feito inúmeras perguntas que caem no hipotético e claro que o seu esforço em aprender é valido, mas é o tipo de pergunta que vai pro amplo demais, sei que a documentação do w3.org é bastante confusa, mas se procurar a fazer perguntas mais de problemas reais talvez sejam mais aceitas. Não estou dizendo que não são "problemas irreais", mas ainda sim talvez se for um pouco mais trabalhada...

Comment: @IngridFarabulini ...ainda sim acho a sua pergunta válida, apesar de trazer pouca utilidade pra uso no dia a dia, por exemplo eu vou desenvolver uma página eu realmente não vou procurar o que é permitido na tag `<html>`, vou simplesmente criar uma página básica, agora se o que você quer é criar alguma tecnologia baseada em DOM, como um Crawler ou manipulação via Javascript a sua pergunta me parece totalmente válida, o problema é que isso não é citado na pergunta. De qualquer forma vou responder ela  - Considere como dicas construtivas.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento muito obrigada pelas palavras, vou procurar continuar a melhorar. Você sempre me ajudou bastante desde que me cadastrei, só tenho a agradecer. Obrigada ;)

Comment: Sua resposta estava muito boa até o seu penúltimo parágrafo. Não caiu muito bem o tom condescendente ao chamar de "justiceiros" as pessoas que se incomodam com o que vêem como mal uso do voto negativo (especalmente contra novatos) _em uma pergunta de um usuário que cai nessa descrição_. Além disso, você disse que o mal uso dos votos negativos vem principalmente desses usuários. Sua afirmação é bastante forte para algo que _carece de fontes_.

Comment: @PabloAlmeida é porque você entendeu errado, eu nunca disse que as pessoas que se incomodam com o mal uso do downvote é que bancam de justiceiro, eu sou um que se incomoda com isto. Eu disse que tem pessoas que não entendem a comunidade (em vários quesitos) e começam a bancar de justiceiros então ae sim usam os votos negativos de maneira incorreta, usam pra atacar quem eles acham estar errados, mesmo na verdade sendo eles não entendendo a atitudo...

Comment: @PabloAlmeida ... Já recebi downvote por fechar pergunta, já recebi downvote por tentar fazer critica construtiva, já recebi downvote por apontar problemas, a maioria das pessoas que chega aqui a pouco não entende como funciona a ferramenta e levam muitas coisas pro lado pessoal. Teve um cara uma vez que começou uma série de downvotes em várias perguntas minhas e isso começou depois que eu fiz uma critica construtiva na resposta dele, ou seja se isso não é querer bancar o **"justiceiro"** (justiça pra ele) eu não sei o que é então. Alguns acham que somos maus quando fechamos uma pergunta :/

Comment: Acho que entendi agora. Eu havia relido algumas vezes o que você escreveu porque estava pouco condizente com o resto do texto, mas foi a única interpretação que consegui fazer. Obrigado pelo esclarecimento e desculpe o mau entendido!

Comment: @PabloAlmeida Tranquilo, eu editei o texto pra melhorar o entendimento. Veja como ficou o penúltimo paragrafo.

Comment: Ficou melhor, sim. E agora que editou posso retirar o meu voto negativo. :)

Comment: @PabloAlmeida Obrigado por esclarecer =)

Answer (score 9):

É muito simples, os votos servem para classificar o conteúdo. Sem +1 ou -1 a gente não vai saber se aquela pergunta/resposta é boa ou não.

Voto negativo por causa de gramática é algo despropositado, qualquer usuário pode propor ou editar diretamente, o esquema Wiki está no DNA do site.

Conteúdo fora de escopo, que não está claro, que não parece útil, que é uma tentativa de vampirizar o esforço alheio... esse tipo de conteúdo leva negativo.

Só 1 negativo não significa muito. Se são mais de um, por favor, vá correndo à Central de Ajuda para tentar entender como funciona o site. Ninguém aqui é obrigado a explicar nada, o voto negativo por si só já é um recado e esses textos foram escritos com carinho para seu melhor proveito do site. Custa só alguns minutos.

## [Central de ajuda - Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: Vejo muitos votos negativos que provavelmente indicam que a pergunta está fora do escopo do site (sem justificativas). Mas o escopo completo do que é aceito ou não não está na Central de Ajuda.

Comment: @PabloAlmeida neste caso, abra uma questão aqui no meta para discutir a pergunta que foi negativada. Isso vai atrair a atenção e definir se está ou não no escopo.

Comment: @Pablo, confere lá no [tour] na seção "Obtenha respostas para perguntas práticas e detalhadas", em teoria "o que perguntar" e "o que não perguntar" são basicamente o escopo do site. E, o que disse o EMBarbosa, se implicarem com uma pergunta, trás aqui pro Meta (moderadores e usuários hardcore estão sempre aqui).

Comment: Concordo com a abordagem, eu dou negativos quando acho que merece levar negativo, se já está cheio de negativos não vou "bater em cachorro morto", mas esta é apenas a minha forma de dar negativos, cada um tem a sua. Não há uma regra exata.

Comment: Acho que não existe pergunta ruim, só perguntas problemáticas que nesse caso deveriam ter atenção dos moderadores nesse caso. Sem falar que vale muito mais a pena comentar, ou editar a pergunta para ajudar o outro, do que negativar e ficar por isso mesmo

Comment: @Sveen "Faça meu dever de casa pra mim" ou "O briefing do meu projeto é X, Y e Z. Qual o código?" são perguntas objetivamente ruins. Se quiser comentar,  tudo bem; editar não faz sentido; pessoalmente, vou negativar e passar pra uma pergunta que valha meu tempo.